# Error: There are uncommitted transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I open a new window in SSMS and run this:

```
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[zzz_test2]
(
    @a    int
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @a=1
    RETURN 0
GO
```

and then close the window, which results in this warning:

`There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these before closing the window?`

what is going on??

when I open a new SSMS window and run this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS  ON  
GO    

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[zzz_test2]
(
    @a    int
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @a=1
    RETURN 0
GO
```

and close the window, I get no warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188340.aspx)  for `ANSI_DEFAULTS`

> When enabled (ON), this option enables
>   the following ISO settings:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS
SET ANSI_PADDING
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
SET ANSI_WARNINGS
```

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) when `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` is on.

> Transactions that are automatically
>   opened as the result of this setting
>   being ON must be explicitly committed
>   or rolled back by the user at the end
>   of the transaction