# Hardcore: Error on Page_Unload. There are 1 uncommited transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I'm trying to debug an application error only by reviewing SQL profiler. (***I don't have access to the code***).

The error in the application says[image]

Now, I ran SQL profiler when executing the frontend command and tried to identify the command which wasn't commited. I can't post the exact queries, but I'll post their main parts.

In the profiler `ROLLBACK` was called after the following update statemant (from what I know only INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements are rollbacked).

```
UPDATE transactions
SET refference = N':ICBilling 8/9/2013'
  ,type1 = 1
  ,notes = N'Billing'
  ,dateModified = convert(DATETIME, N'08/09/2013 10:33:13AM', 101)
  ,moduleModifiedBy = N'PM'
WHERE transaction_id = 1100001368
```

I scrolled up the profiler to see what happened before and observed that this record was inserted into `transactions` table.

```
INSERT INTO transactions (
  transaction_id,
  uRefference,
  Type1,
  Notes,
  ModuleModifiedBy,   
  )
VALUES (
  1100001368
  , NULL
  , 0
  , NULL
  , convert(DATETIME, N'08/09/2013 10:33:13AM', 101)
  )
```

Right before this insert there was a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` command. I assumed that because the `INSERT` opperation was not commited into the `Transactions` table, the `UPDATE` statement would cause an error, because it couldn't find the record to update.

(Although I have tested in SQL Server this idea with these queries. I created a temp table and ran the part right after `begin transaction` in one go)

```
CREATE TABLE #tempx (i INT);
INSERT INTO #tempx VALUES (1),(2),(3);

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO #tempx VALUES (4);

UPDATE #tempx
SET i = 5
WHERE i = 4
```

The queries ran and the `UPDATE` was executed without a problem, so I have sort of eliminated this possibility. Although I had my doubts about the difference between runnign queries directly from SQL Server M.S. and calling them from an application and after further googling I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378357/error-there-are-uncommitted-transactions)) that a few parameters have to be set in order to have implicit transactions.

So, I went back to my profiler and right at the top this is what I found

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
SET LANGUAGE us_english
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
SET DATEFIRST 7
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

I haven't tried to set `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` to `ON` yet because this is a production DB and I'm not entirely sure there will be no problems.

So, I would like to ask the help of people with more experience to help me find or at least drill down to a place where the problem might be (the code or in SQL Server settings)

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get access to the part of the code that throws the error

```
If Not myExceptionOccured And Not SessionKey Is Nothing Then
   If SessionKey.Connection.IsInTranState Then
            Dim Message As String = String.Format("Could not complete Page_Unload. There are {0} uncommitted transactions. All changes were rolled back.", SessionKey.Connection.TransactionCount)
```

so it is clear at this moment that the session is not being closed and transaction is not being commited by SQL Server.

I've tried modifying other transactions and that worked. But apparently it has a problem only with this transaction. I'll try comparing both profilers for these transactions, maybe I can find a difference.

In the meantime, if anyone thinks I'm going in the wrong direction, please leave a comment.

**UPDATE #2:**

Like I've said, I profiled another transaction which worked and looked at the query after which rollback is called.

The query, in both cases (in the case where it works and when it rollbacks), is this (the same as at the beginning of my question):

```
UPDATE transactions
SET refference = N':Billing 8/16/2013'
  ,type1 = 1
  ,notes = N'Billing'
  ,dateModified = convert(DATETIME, N'08/16/2013 12:47:25PM', 101)
  ,moduleModifiedBy = N'PM'
WHERE tranId = --transaction id here--
```

The only difference between them is the transaction ID which they update, and the times (there's a `GETDATE()` function which gets the current time).

*And that is just it. One transaction is commited, the other is not.*

**Any other suggestions?**

Comment: It's not clear - are the INSERT and UPDATE statements on separate connections?  (In other words, one connection is doing the insert, but you've not committed it yet, and a separate connection is doing the update on the record that's not committed by the first connection?)

Comment: @MarkSowul Well, if there were sepparate connections, what could make it in one case to continue and in the other to not commit? I asume you're trying to suggest the error is in the code and not on the data layer, correct?